# Error in updating Carthage in Xcode 11 and Swift 5

Tags: ios, xcode11, swift5, carthage, contentful

I'm trying to upgrade my project from Xcode 10.2(Swift 4.2) to Xcode 11(Swift 5). But I'm getting error while Carthage upgrade as below: (It's specifically for `contentful.swift` framework only)

```
carthage update --platform iOS // I'm running this command in terminal.
```

Error:

```
*** Fetching contentful.swift
A shell task (/usr/bin/env git fetch --prune --quiet https://github.com/contentful/contentful.swift.git refs/tags/*:refs/tags/* +refs/heads/*:refs/heads/* (launched in /Users/My_Name/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/dependencies/contentful.swift)) failed with exit code 1
```

Can someone please help to find the issue where I'm doing wrong?

I also even tried importing build framework of `contentful.swift` but still I was getting different error in Xcode.

I'm not able to run my project in Xcode 11. It's building successfully in Xcode 10.2.

Comment: You might need to clean out your carthage cache, which is in `~/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit`. Remove that folder, then try running carthage again.